# How to set default role for user registration

Tags: php

I want to set default user ( Trainees role ) for newly registered user on my system.
My main problem is registration works but the 'role' tab on the database is empty. Tried adding dropdown button for trainees role but the 'role' tab on the users table is still empty.

Is it allowed to set default user role upon user registration?

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBdO4.png)

Registration.php code

```
     <?php

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

require_once "php/dbconnect.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])!="") {
header("Location: index.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$emailid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['emailid']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['age']); 
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']); 
$role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['role']); 
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
$name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
}
if(!filter_var($emailid,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
}
if(strlen($password) < 6) {
$password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
}       
if(strlen($mobile) < 10) {
$mobile_error = "Mobile number must be minimum of 10 characters";
}
if($password != $cpassword) {
$cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
}
if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user(username,password,name,emailid,age,location,role) VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . md5($password) . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $emailid . "','" . $age . "','" . $location . "','" . $role . "')")) {
header("location:http://localhost/test/?url=users_index");

exit();

} else {
    $error = 'Invalid Username or Password';
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Registration Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>G&L Management System</title>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<style>
    @font-face {
  font-family: Poppins;
  src: url("fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf");
}

html * {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.myhead{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="banner.png" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;">
</center>
    <div class="container">
        
         <div class="row ">
               
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: #E2E2E2; margin-top:70px; box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;">
                              <h3 class="myhead">User Registration</h3>
                                <form role="form" action="register.php" method="post">                               
<br>
<label>Username</label>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<div class="form-group input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"  ></i><?php if (isset($username_error)) echo $username_error; ?></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username" name="username" required />
                                        </div>
                                        <label>Password</label>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"  ></i><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>
<input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
</div>
<label>Name</label>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<div class="form-group input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"  ></i><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name" name="name" required />
                                        </div>
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"  ></i><?php if (isset($emailid_error)) echo $emailid_error; ?></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email" name="emailid" required />
</div>
<label>Age</label>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-child"  ></i><?php if (isset($age_error)) echo $age_error; ?></span>
<input type="number" class="form-control"  placeholder="Age" name="age" required />
</div>
<label>Location</label>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"  ></i><?php if (isset($location_error)) echo $location_error; ?></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Location" name="location" required />
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="signup" value="Submit">



                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
            Already have an account? 
                <p><a href="login.php">Login Here</a></p>
            </div>
                                    
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                
                
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that code is for handling the accepted form data, are you sending the data correctly from the form posting to this code?

Comment: Yes i did that sir

Comment: Say if the role column is char(100), then use `alter table user modify column role char(100) default 'trainees' ` to add the default value , then remove the role field from your insert query

Comment: You are storing user's passwords in plain text - admittedly in a hashed format ( `md5` is broken and is **not** suitable for user's passwords ) and as soon as I saw `mysqli_real_escape_string` knew you were not using `prepared statements`

Comment: well clearly there's no form object called "role" that is sent from the Registration Form thus, it will always be empty. 
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username" name="username" required />
you need something like that with name="role" to be recognized as $_POST['role'] in the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set default value for column "role" to trainee, that way whenever new user is created it is assigned role of trainee automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ALTER `role` SET DEFAULT "trainees";
```

otherwise you can add drop down like this

```
  <label for="role">Choose a role:</label>
  <select id="role" name="role">
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="coach">Coach</option>
    <option value="trainees">Trainees</option>
  </select>
```